# How to avoid monochromatic cycles?

Tags: graphs, colorings

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider a simple and connected undirected graph $G(V,E)$. Show that one can colour the edges of $G$ in polynomial time and with as few colours as possible such that there is no monochromatic cycle in said colouring of $G$.

EDIT 1: OK, my approach turned out to be false. I will leave it here for the sake of completeness. Now I have no idea how to solve this exercise. I guess the following theorem might be helpful:

> Theorem: For any undirected simple graph $G(V,E)$ we can decide whether the [edge chromatic number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EdgeChromaticNumber.html) is less than $3$ and if yes we can find this optimal colouring in polynomial time.

EDIT 2: I have reread my lecture notes. This exercise is probably meant to be solved with tools from matroid theory. I just do not see how.

---

My WRONG approach:

I think that 2 colours should be sufficient. (Remember that this is not the classical edge colouring problem, we just want to avoid monochromatic cycles.) My first idea is to formulate a simple greedy algorithm:

1. Colour all edges in red.
2. Check the graph for cycles. If there is a cycle delete one edge of the cycle from the graph. Repeat this step until there are no more cycles in $G$.
3. Colour the deleted edges in blue.

However, the problem with this approach is that the blue edges may form a cylce as the example below shows. While the example below can easily be fixed by recolouring two edges I am not sure if this fix works in general. Could you please give me a hint?[image]

Comment: Deciding whether a given directed graph can be vertex partitioned into two acyclic subgraphs [is][1] $\text{NP}$-complete. So we know the problem is hard for directed graphs. Why you think it is easier for undirected ones? Did I miss something?!

  [1]: https://feb.kuleuven.be/public/u0004371/published%20papers/coloring%20graphs%20with%20two%20colors.pdf

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi The reference you shared is for the vertex coloring. It is not for the edge coloring. :)

Comment: @Inuyashayagami Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: I will make an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is find the arboricity of the graph, or equivalently compute the minimum partition into independent sets in the graphic matroid. This problem (for a general matroid) is known as the [Matroid partitioning problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_partitioning), for which polynomial-time algorithms exist.

You can find more details in [Harold N. Gabow and Herbert H. Westermann, Forests, frames, and games: Algorithms for matroid sums and applications](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01758774).